# Netbeans web project can not read CSS file

Tags: css, jsp

I'm out of solutions here. Have been trying to solve this for half a day now!!! My jsp can not read my CSS file. I've tried the very simplest file structure here. I put both jsp and CSS under "Web Pages".

So

```
MyProject
   -Web Pages
      -WEB-INF
      -login.jsp
      -logincss.css
   -etc...
```

jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="logincss.css">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>why you CSS wont WORK!!!</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
body
{
background-color: red;
}
```

So I write href="logincss.css" because both jsp and the css are on the same level. But still this does not work! I have the simplest html and simplest css but it does not work! I think the problem is on the Project itself. I just created a new web project, create jsp and css, try it out and it worked!

Please help me I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks.